# Read in .JSON files as a list of lists

Tags: json, r, dplyr

Say I have a set of .JSON files, of type T1, T2...TN in my working directory, and for each type there are a different number (n) of files. Each .JSON file is a list of data frames.

Reading these in is simple:

```
library(jsonlite)
T1_l <- lapply(list.files(pattern = "T1"), fromJSON, flatten = TRUE)
T2_l <- lapply(list.files(pattern = "T2"), fromJSON, flatten = TRUE)
.
.
.
TN_l <- lapply(list.files(pattern = "TN"), fromJSON, flatten = TRUE)
```

I can subset for the content I want, which is simply a dataframe within each list, by:

```
T1_c <- lapply(T1_l, function(x) {x$content})
T2_c <- lapply(T2_l, function(x) {x$content})
.
.
.
TN_c <- lapply(TN_l, function(x) {x$content})
```

Then I can bind this content into a single dataframe by:

```
library(dplyr)
T1_df <- bind_rows(T1_c)
T2_df <- bind_rows(T2_c)
.
.
.
TN_df <- bind_rows(TN_c)
```

If I had 100s, or 1000s of these .JSON file types, this workflow would require a function. But in the name of simplicity, I want a function that automates this process, and outputs a set of dataframes (named T1_df, T2_df...TN_df) to my global environment. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'd caution against outputting each data.frame to the global environment. It's a better idea to keep them in a list of (desired) data.frames, or maybe better a data.frame with a list column of data.frames. Both are much easier to further manipulate.

Comment: I agree. Part of my intention with wrapping this workflow into a function is to keep my global environment free of large lists and subsetted lists. Ultimately, I do need each type in my global environment as a dataframe so I can do some analysis, but I surely don't need the intermediate processing steps as variables.

Comment: If you have a lot of rectangular JSON data and regularly need to query it, I may also recommend checking out Apache Drill and [sergeant](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/sergeant), which will let you query it directly from disk as if it were a SQL database. Since it can glob, you can slurp up files (even nested ones) into a single data.frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply extend your `lapply` function for a binded dataframe:

```
# BASE R: IF COLUMNS ARE SAME
T1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files(pattern = "T1"), function(j)
                            fromJSON(j, flatten = TRUE)$content))
# DPLYR: IF COLUMNS DIFFER
T1 <- bind_rows(lapply(list.files(pattern = "T1"), function(j)
                       fromJSON(j, flatten = TRUE)$content))
```

And to capture each binded dataframe in a dataframe list, use nested `lapply`:

```
t_list <- c("T1", "T2", ..., "TN")

df_list <- lapply(t_list, function(t)
            do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files(pattern = t), function(j)
                                  fromJSON(j, flatten = TRUE)[['content']])))
```

Even name each df element and then output individual dataframes to global environment as separate objects (though not advised if hundreds of dfs):

```
df_list <- setNames(df_list, t_list)

list2env(df_list, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was really looking for a function to wrap this entire process up into a few compact lines of code. Thanks @Parafit--this function is based on your answer.

This function takes a vector of file patterns, reads in .JSON files with that pattern, extracts content, and binds together files of a particular pattern in a dataframe.

```
files_to_df <- function(pattern){
  bind_rows(lapply(list.files(pattern = pattern), function(j) 
    fromJSON(j, flatten = TRUE)$content))
}
```

The patterns to apply to the function

```
patterns <- c('abstracts', 'people', 'sessions', 'slots', 'rooms')
```

Here, we apply `patterns` to the `files_to_df` function, set names of the dataframes as the names within `pattern`, then export these dataframes to the global environment

```
list2env(setNames(lapply(patterns, files_to_df), patterns), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```